# how to extend a least square classifier to a multiclass scenario

Tags: r, classification, least-squares

I would like to implement a Linear Least Square classifier and I am having some difficulties in 2 aspects:

1. How would I test the accuracy in this case? I separated a % for training and other % to test but I am not sure how to evaluate it. I computed `f(x) = sum(c*K(x,xi))`, and by using `sign(f)` I am able to get the prediction, right? but How to extend it to the test % to get its model accuracy?
2. And how would I extend it to a multiclass scenario?

Thanks in advance.

I am using R, and this is what I coded so far:
`x_train` is my train data, and `y_train` are the labels{-1,1}.

```r
K<-gausskernel(X=x_train,sigma=1)
c<-solve((dim(x_train)[1]*diag(dim(x_train)[1])+K),y_train)

f<-matrix(0,nrow=nrow(K),ncol=1)
for(j in 1:dim(K)[1]){
  for (i in 1:dim(K)[1]){
    f[j,]<- f[j,] + c[i]*K[j,i]

  }
}
```